# Need an actual SSH client library for python, not a spawner

Tags: python, ssh

I need a helper library that actually makes an ssh connection. Not one that spawns another app to do so. (eg: pexpect). It also needs support automating the CLI interface. However it needs to be similar to pexpect in that it needs to wait for input (ie: a prompt with certain text in it). Ultimately it needs to be cross platform too (this why pexpect is a poor choice). Also very important to note: I am **not** logging into a linux shell. This is a custom CLI app. It must also support SSH, not SSH2.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the simplest way to SSH using Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1233655/what-is-the-simplest-way-to-ssh-using-python)

Comment: @Martijin Pieters: No. That question is closed already and IS the duplicate.

Comment: I don't think we are talking about the same question..

Comment: Related: [Why no pure Python SSH1 (version 1) client implementations?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/936783/why-no-pure-python-ssh1-version-1-client-implementations)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[**paramiko**](https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko) or its [fork **ssh**](https://github.com/bitprophet/ssh) are ssh client implementations in native Python.

However, both only support the newer ssh v2 protocol. ssh v1 was fundamentally flawed. It is [basically an obfuscated telnet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/936783/why-no-pure-python-ssh1-version-1-client-implementations) and has been deprecated for a decade. Therefore, it is no longer in wide use.

If the remote supports it, use [telnetlib](http://docs.python.org/library/telnetlib.html) to establish a telnet connection.

Comment: I don't think I can use these... SSH2 isn't cross compatible with SSH: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Shell#Version_2.x

Comment: @Zombies: You never specified you needed SSH1 compatibility.

Comment: @Zombies: With the advent of SSH2, the old protocol is now referred to as SSH1 (or 'SSH protocol version 1)', as the term `SSH` is ambiguous, as you've now surely discovered.

Comment: @Zombies: From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Shell): *"The protocol specification distinguishes two major versions that are referred to as SSH-1 and SSH-2."* As SSH2 has been around for 6 years now, *and* is the more secure variant, hardly anyone uses SSH1 anymore. If you need SSH1 compat, you need to specify that explicitly.

Comment: @Zombies ssh1 is insecure (it doesn't even have a MAC) and therefore no longer used anymore. As to the allegation that I'm "blasting out as many answers as I can": I don't see what should be wrong with quickly answering a question, and looking at my [activity tab](http://stackoverflow.com/users/35070/phihag?tab=activity), you can see I blasted out ... *one* answer today.

Comment: @Zombies, insulting someone who's trying to help isn't likely to give you the answer you seek.